# Other than Madara, who among the Uchiha Clan possesses or successfully awaken the Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto

I'm just curious whether if only Madara possesses the Rinnegan and if not how many are there?
What are the chances that Sasuke can awaken his Rinnegan?

Comment: If it's about awakening, then I think it's only Madara and Sasuke (only known Uchihas having successfully transplanted DNA of both Indra and Ashura)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized that the correct answer may be potentially wrong.

As we have seen thus far, Madara and Obito are the only 2 Uchiha to have used the Rinnegan. Aside from them, Sasuke is the only other Uchiha clan member that is still alive, whom hasn't awaken the Rinnegan yet.

With that said, Sasuke is potentially capable of awakening the Rinnegan any second now. Sasuke has bitten Karin many times. Karin is an Uzumaki, which is a distant relative of the Senju. That means Sasuke has Senju cells inside of him!

With the DNA requirements fulfilled, Sasuke can pull a quick one and activate Rinnegan stunning Madara, the Shinobi alliance, and all of us readers :)

**Updated with known Rinnegan users:
Madara,
Obito,
Sasuke,
Sage of 6 Paths,
Kaguya**

Comment: This is the reason why I love Kishimoto as an author. He is able to connect past events to future events very well as he creates these small, but important details. Then if he ever wants to, he can just apply the details in the future.

Comment: I never said that Sasuke is not capable of awakening the Rinnegan, he's just not yet capable of it. And the purpose of biting Karin is to absorb chakra from her, not cells from her.

Comment: @NixR.Eyes You specifically said `Sasuke will only be able to activate rinnegan if he has Hashirama's cells with him` , which is not true. As for Karin's situation, we understand the purpose was not to gain Rinnegan, but like I said in my previous comment, Kishi likes to connect the past and the future with specific details. Sometimes actions can serve one purpose, and then lead to a totally new result.

Comment: Kaguya doesn't have a Rinnegan. She has a Rinne Sharingan.

Answer (score 2):

So far as the manga goes, only Madara was seen to activate the Rinnegan. Even Nagato's rinnegan was given to him by Madara before his death.

And so all the rinnegan shown belongs to Madara.

Sasuke will only be able to activate rinnegan if he has Hashirama's cells with him. And i guess he currently don't have it.

Comment: can you please point out where it has been indicated that yo awaken the rinnegan you need to have hashirama's cells?

Comment: It is stated here http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinnegan#cite_ref-4

Comment: You don't need Hashirama's cells per se. What you need is some form of Senju DNA combined with the Uchiha Sharingan.

Comment: I far as I remember, Nagato has "normal eyes" when he was young. When he saw his parents killed by a Konoha Shinobi, he awaken the Rinnegan and killed them. Isn't that event accounted for?

Comment: So why doesn't Obito have it?

Comment: @TAAPSogeking - Even obito has the Rinnegan. He took it from Nagato's body after he died.

Comment: @R.J But why didn't/couldn't he get it on his own like Madara?

Comment: @TAAPSogeking - He couldn't awaken it. Though he had both the Uchiha and Senju DNA, he wasn't as powerful as Madara, plus his mastery over both the DNA wasn't that great. Also, Madara himself awakened the Rinnegan in the very last days of his life. Its natural process and not exactly in the hands of Obito.

Comment: According to the wiki, it's not Uchiha and Senju DNA mixing but Asura's and Indra's chakra mixing, meaning ONLY Madara / Sasuke would ever be capable of awakening it. Both of them were able to through acquiring Hashirama cells which had traces of Asura's chakra. Every Rinnegan we've seen ((Besides Sasuke's Shar-Rinnegan)) was Madara's eyes implanted in another -- It's a somewhat major plot point in the 4th War, and led to Konan's death as well.

Answer (score 0):

As an updated answer, It turns out it was not as simple as we thought, though it took the Sage himself to explain it.

Based on the Musings of Hagoromo (the Sage of Six paths) He inherited His rinnegan from his mother, which was then split to each of his children, Indra and Ashura. It is the combination of their chakras that result in the rinnegan (Indra + Asura = Hagoromo). The brothers however had a Feud, which somehow caused their Unique chakras to reincarnate into their decedents. Coincidentally, they happen to be Uchiha and Senju respectively, which is where the initial confusion happened with only need Uchiha and Senju DNA. This is shown best with Danzo, who had Uchiha and Senju DNA for Years, possibly around the time of Narutos birth, but does not have any Rinnegan eyes in that collection. 
Eventually, the Chakras reincarnated into Madara and Hashirama. Madara obtained the Rinnegan because he was Indras reincarnation and therefor had Indras charkra, and then he took on Asuras chakra from Hashirama, who was Asuras Reincarnation. This mix (Asura and Indra) becomes the Sage of Six paths, with the Rinnegan.

Madara then gave both of his eyes to Nagato, since Nagato could not naturally obtain them. Rinnegan appear to work like all other Dojutsu in that the eyes themselves retain their form even after transplanting, as Nagato could never undo them, they were permanently rinnegan. After Nagatos death, Obito took his eyes. Obito is unable to awaken the Rinnegan naturally because he is not Indras reincarnation, and so is still missing Indras chakra despite having Uchiha and Asura's charkas. he had to implant the Rinnegan, which he could only implant one of due to their power.

This boils down to meaning that Only Madara and Hashirama could obtain the Rinnegan from the older characters, And the current generation of Reincarnations, Naruto and Sasuke as well. Of course, if someone could implant Sasukes eyes and implement Narutos DNA, they could also obtain the rinnegan eventually.